# Prevent user paste in fields

Tags: javascript

I want to prevent a user from pasting anything into my input field.

This is what I have tried:

```
onpaste="event.returnValue=false;"
```

Comment: Please don't do that, it's just annoying. (When I come across these, I disable it using the Developer Tools and it wastes time.) If you're doing it for something like a password or e-mail confirmation, doubly so; people use things like KeePass that manage passwords for extra security, and this kind of thing makes that frustrating.

Comment: @minitech related: [Preventing a user from pasting from the clipboard into a mandatory form field (from User Experience)](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21062/preventing-a-user-from-pasting-from-the-clipboard-into-a-mandatory-form-field)

Comment: Preventing pasting like this does not prevent users from dragging a selection into the input field. Btw, I totally agree with @minitech

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" onPaste="return false;">
```